# Adding days to date in Java Error

Tags: java, date, jodatime

Here's my code. I'm the `joda` library for managing time on Java.

```
int dayOffset = 100;
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");

LocalDate ldate = new LocalDate().plusDays(dayOffset);
Date date = ldate.toDate();

String s = dateFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(s);
```

I ran this code on `13/01/2015` and I'm getting the output as `113/04/2015` which is obviously not a valid date. What am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. This issue has been addressed *many* time before. You would have found hundreds of examples which you could have compared to your code.

Comment: @Basil, I did search quite a bit. I assumed it was a problem with the joda lib which made me include that in my search query, which is probably why I didn't find results. I did not contemplate there was an error with my date format string. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [`SimpleDateFormat` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), if you use capital `DD`, which means "day of year", then it makes sense that adding 100 days yields day `113`.

You should use `dd` (lowercase), which means "day of month".

Also, you should use lowercase `yyyy` for year; `YYYY` means "week year".